# Best practice for implementing custom form in Vue

Tags: javascript, vue.js, validation

My goal is to create a custom form component called `app-form` which provides `v-model` to access the validation. For the input I want to detect is also a custom component called `app-input`.
Here is my implementation so far.

**app-form**

```html
<template>
  <div>
    <slot></slot>
  </div>
</template>
```

```js
const acceptedTags = ['app-input'];
export default {
  /*
  props: value,
  data: isValid
  */
  updated() {
    // update isValid whenever the view changes
    this.checkValidation();
  },
  methods: {
    checkValidation() {
      this.isValid = true;
      this.checkValidation(this);
      this.$emit('input', this.isValid);
    },
    checkValidationRecursion(node) {
      if (acceptedTags.includes(node.$options.name)) {
          let result = node.checkValidation();
          this.isValid &&= result;
      }
      node.$children.forEach((child) => this.checkValidationRecursion(child));
    },
  }
}
```

**app-input**

```html
<input
  :value="selfValue"
  @input="onInput"/>
```

```js
export default {
  name: 'app-input',
  /*
  props: value,
  data: selfValue,
  */
  methods: {
    checkValidation() {
      let valid = true;
      /*
        this.rules = [(v) => !!v || 'Required'];
      */
      for (let f of this.rules) {
        let result = f(this.selfValue);
        if (typeof result === 'string') {
          valid = false;
        }
      }
      return valid;
    },
    // onInput() => update selfValue and emit
  },
  // watch: update selfValue
}
```

In the code above, the `app-form` have to traverse the whole component tree to get the target inputs every time anything is updated. Is there any better way to achieve it?

Answer (score 0, accepted):

For these Kind of things I like to use provide/inject https://v2.vuejs.org/v2/api/#provide-inject. The idea is to "provide" an object in a Parent-Component (your Form-Component) and to "inject" this object in any of your descandant Components. Data here is not reactive, but you can pass a reference to a reactive Object (for example a Vue Object).

If providing a Vue-Instance you can emit an event, like "check-validation" on that instance and your descandant components can listen to that and then emitting an validate-Event with the validation-Result back to the parent Component.

Here is a very basic Example: https://codepen.io/arossbach/pen/xxdxOVZ

```
            Vue.component('my-form', {
              provide () {
                return {
                  formBus: this.formBus,
                };
              },
              mounted() {
                setTimeout(() => {
                  this.formBus.$emit("check-validation");
                },4000);
                
                this.formBus.$on("validate-element", isValid => {     
                  this.isValidForm &&= isValid;
                });
              },
              data () {
                return {
                  formBus: new Vue(),
                  isValidForm: true,
                };
              },
              template: '<div><slot></slot></div>',
             
            });

            Vue.component('child', {
              inject: ['formBus'],
              template: '<div></div>',
              data() {
                return {
                 isValid: true,
                }
              },
              methods: {
                validate() {

                  this.isValid = Boolean(Math.round(Math.random()));
                  this.formBus.$emit("validate-element", this.isValid);
                }
              },
              created() {
                this.formBus.$on("check-validation", this.validate);
              }
            });

            new Vue({
              el: '#app',
              data () {
                return {
                };
              },
            });
```

HTML:

```
<div id="app">
  <my-form>
    <child></child>
    <child></child>
  </my-form>
</div>
```

Comment: Did this answers help you, kswang?

Comment: Sorry for the late reply. Sure! This is what exactly I am look for. Actually, I traced the code of VForm (Vuetify) and got the same solution (provide/inject) as you provided.